# Can't get how to apply Implicit Symmetric QR Step and symmetric QR to small matrices

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

[image]

The main issue is that I don't understand how to apply this algorithm to, for instance, matrix 3x3. Should all matrices of size 2x2 be treated as Hessenberg unreduced? How should I apply algorithm 8.3.2(Implicit Symmetric QR Step with Wilkinson Shift) to 2x2 matrix?

P.S.
It's Goulub and Van Loan book "Matrix computations"

Comment: A 2x2 matrix *is* Hessenberg.  But consider direction computation of the Eigenvalues.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You mean that this algorithms (like QR step with Wilkinson shift and symmetric QR) can only be applied to big matrices and for small matrices (like 2x2) direct computations for eigenvalues should be done? (like if D22 is a 2x2 it should be replaced with matrix that has D22's eigenvalues on main diagonal)

Comment: No, this is not what I mean, but I think it would be overkill to use the general method for small matrices.

Comment: Hmm, the main issue is on how to use QR step, when D22 is small, sad that I've misunderstood you